# Can not disable screen locking after suspend in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, suspend, lock, metacity, gnome-flashback

I updated from 18.04 to 20.04 and since then unable to disable lock screen, despite it was disabled in 18.04. Corresponding setting in the gui does not take effect, so does `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false` or `xset s off`. I also tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` (the setting was sddm, and i changed it to gdm3) with the same effect.

After suspension i get picture with purple fossa and password field, in which i can not change keyboard layout with keyboard, but only with mouse. My session is gnome-flashback metacity. The lock screen does not appear after screensaver (i use xscreensaver).

However once this lock screen stopped to appear, but at the same time the system started to enter suspend mode randomly and quite often. After rebooting the lock screens came back.

Also the sound volume is set to "mute" sometimes after suspend.

How can i disable such lock screen?

Thanks in advance.

`journalctl -xe` starting at the beginning of suspension (unfortunately it is in part in russian and this site treats it as spam) : https://gist.github.com/dining-philosopher/14dcc6b9cc58d0dc0923d11d699696ae

Comment: Please create launchpad.net bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-flashback/+filebug.

Comment: @muktupavels done https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-flashback/+bug/1891681