# Can not enter password on lock screen in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, suspend, lock, metacity, gnome-flashback

I was able to enter my password on ubuntu purple focal fossa lock screen ([however i never wanted this screen to appear](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265613/can-not-disable-screen-locking-after-suspend-in-20-04#)). Until now. Today i tried to enter the password, but failed to do this. The password field remains completely blank, and if i hit the login button with mouse, it says the password was incorrect.

Moreover, it seems that the keyboard input goes straight to other applications, e. g. i can switch between windows with alt+tab (and window list is shown (but no lock screen in this list)) and start/stop youtube videos (sound from which is played) with space key. So ironically it lost focus.

When i push "change user" button, user selection screen appears, and i can enter the correct password there, but i end up with the same focal fossa screen.

However i can log in to command line with ctrl+alt+f* or ssh.

I tried `gnome-screensaver-command -d` and `loginctl unlock-session`(s) with no effect. Also i tried to find and kill lock screen process and suspend/wake once again, but the effect was the same.

I use gnome-flashback, metacity and xscreensaver.

Also i have to mention that i played factorio yesterday. It was the second time i did that, but the first time i set "minimize on focus loss" option. And with this option it was quite difficult to maximize the factorio back, which i think  is similar to the discussed symptoms (except i can not gain focus on the lock screen cos it is not shown in alt+tab window list). However i exited factorio before suspension.

How i can log in without rebooting or restarting session?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have same bug/problem without `xscreensaver`?

Comment: Is this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-screensaver/+bug/1875025?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use other screensaver application you have to disable built in screensaver in gnome-flashback:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-flashback screensaver false
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by uninstalling xscreensaver:

```
sudo apt-get remove xscreensaver
```